# Parse HTML table data with BeautifulSoup into a dict

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use `BeautifulSoup` to parse the information stored in an HTML table and store it into a dict.  I've been able to get to the table, and iterate through the values, but there is still a lot of junk in the table that I'm not sure how to take care of.

```
# load the HTML file
r = requests.get("http://www.ebay.com/itm/222378225962")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

# navigate to the item attributes table
table = soup.find('div', 'itemAttr')

# iterate through the attribute information
attr = []
for i in table.findAll("tr"):
    attr.append(i.text.strip().replace('\t', ''))
```

With this method, this is what the data looks like.  As you you see, there is a lot of junk in there, and some lines contain multiple items like Year and VIN.

```
[u'Condition:\nUsed',
 u'Seller Notes:\n\u201cExcellent Condition\u201d',
 u'Year: \n\n2015\n\n VIN (Vehicle Identification Number): \n\n2G1FJ1EW2F9192023',
 u'Mileage: \n\n29,000\n\n Transmission: \n\nManual',
 u'Make: \n\nChevrolet\n\n Body Type: \n\nCoupe',
 u'Model: \n\nCamaro\n\n Warranty: \n\nVehicle has an existing warranty',
 u'Trim: \n\nSS Coupe 2-Door\n\n Vehicle Title: \n\nClear',
 u'Engine: \n\n6.2L 6162CC 376Cu. In. V8 GAS OHV Naturally Aspirated\n\n Options: \n\nLeather Seats',
 u'Drive Type: \n\nRWD\n\n Safety Features: \n\nAnti-Lock Brakes, Driver Airbag, Passenger Airbag, Side Airbags',
 u'Power Options: \n\nAir Conditioning, Cruise Control, Power Locks, Power Windows, Power Seats\n\n Sub Model: \n\n1LE',
 u'Fuel Type: \n\nGasoline\n\n Color: \n\nWhite',
 u'For Sale By: \n\nPrivate Seller\n\n Interior Color: \n\nBlack',
 u'Disability Equipped: \n\nNo\n\n Number of Cylinders: \n\n8',
 u'']
```

Ultimately, I want the data to be stored in a dictionary like below.  I know how to create a dictionary, but don't know how to clean up the data that needs to go into the dictionary without brute force find-and-replace.

```
{'Condition' : 'Used',
 'Seller Notes' : 'Excellent Condition',
 'Year': '2015',
 'VIN (Vehicle Identification Number)': '2G1FJ1EW2F9192023',
 'Mileage': '29,000', 
 'Transmission': 'Manual',
 'Make': 'Chevrolet', 
 'Body Type': 'Coupe',
 'Model': 'Camaro', 
 'Warranty': 'Vehicle has an existing warranty',
 'Trim': 'SS Coupe 2-Door',
 'Vehicle Title' : 'Clear',
 'Engine': '6.2L 6162CC 376Cu. In. V8 GAS OHV Naturally Aspirated', 
 'Options': 'Leather Seats',
 'Drive Type': 'RWD', 
 'Safety Features' : 'Anti-Lock Brakes, Driver Airbag, Passenger Airbag, Side Airbags',
 'Power Options' : 'Air Conditioning, Cruise Control, Power Locks, Power Windows, Power Seats',
 'Sub Model' : '1LE',
 'Fuel Type' : 'Gasoline', 
 'Exterior Color' : 'White',
 'For Sale By' : 'Private Seller', 
 'Interior Color' : 'Black',
 'Disability Equipped' : 'No', 
 'Number of Cylinders': '8'}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than trying to parse out the data from the `tr` elements, a better approach would be to iterate over the `td.attrLabels` data elements. You can use these labels as the key, and then use the adjacent sibling elements as the value.

In the example below, the CSS selector `div.itemAttr td.attrLabels` is used to select all `td` elements with `.attrLabels` classes that are descendants of the `div.itemAttr`. From there, the method [`.find_next_sibling()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) is used to find the adjacent sibling element.

```
r = requests.get("http://www.ebay.com/itm/222378225962")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

data = []
for label in soup.select('div.itemAttr td.attrLabels'):
    data.append({ label.text.strip(): label.find_next_sibling().text.strip() })
```

Output:

```
> [{'Year:': '2015'}, {'VIN (Vehicle Identification Number):': '2G1FJ1EW2F9192023'}, {'Mileage:': '29,000'}, {'Transmission:': 'Manual'}, {'Make:': 'Chevrolet'}, {'Body Type:': 'Coupe'}, {'Model:': 'Camaro'}, {'Warranty:': 'Vehicle has an existing warranty'}, {'Trim:': 'SS Coupe 2-Door'}, {'Vehicle Title:': 'Clear'}, {'Engine:': '6.2L 6162CC 376Cu. In. V8 GAS OHV Naturally Aspirated'}, {'Options:': 'Leather Seats'}, {'Drive Type:': 'RWD'}, {'Safety Features:': 'Anti-Lock Brakes, Driver Airbag, Passenger Airbag, Side Airbags'}, {'Power Options:': 'Air Conditioning, Cruise Control, Power Locks, Power Windows, Power Seats'}, {'Sub Model:': '1LE'}, {'Fuel Type:': 'Gasoline'}, {'Exterior Color:': 'White'}, {'For Sale By:': 'Private Seller'}, {'Interior Color:': 'Black'}, {'Disability Equipped:': 'No'}, {'Number of Cylinders:': '8'}]
```

---

If you also want to retrieve the table header `th` elements, then you could select the table element and then use the CSS selector `th, td.attrLabels` in order to retrieve both labels:

```
r = requests.get("http://www.ebay.com/itm/222378225962")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('div', 'itemAttr')

data = []
for label in table.select('th, td.attrLabels'):
    data.append({ label.text.strip(): label.find_next_sibling().text.strip() })
```

Output:

```
> [{'Condition:': 'Used'}, {'Seller Notes:': '“Excellent Condition”'}, {'Year:': '2015'}, {'VIN (Vehicle Identification Number):': '2G1FJ1EW2F9192023'}, {'Mileage:': '29,000'}, {'Transmission:': 'Manual'}, {'Make:': 'Chevrolet'}, {'Body Type:': 'Coupe'}, {'Model:': 'Camaro'}, {'Warranty:': 'Vehicle has an existing warranty'}, {'Trim:': 'SS Coupe 2-Door'}, {'Vehicle Title:': 'Clear'}, {'Engine:': '6.2L 6162CC 376Cu. In. V8 GAS OHV Naturally Aspirated'}, {'Options:': 'Leather Seats'}, {'Drive Type:': 'RWD'}, {'Safety Features:': 'Anti-Lock Brakes, Driver Airbag, Passenger Airbag, Side Airbags'}, {'Power Options:': 'Air Conditioning, Cruise Control, Power Locks, Power Windows, Power Seats'}, {'Sub Model:': '1LE'}, {'Fuel Type:': 'Gasoline'}, {'Exterior Color:': 'White'}, {'For Sale By:': 'Private Seller'}, {'Interior Color:': 'Black'}, {'Disability Equipped:': 'No'}, {'Number of Cylinders:': '8'}]
```

---

If you want to strip out non-alphanumeric character(s) for the keys, then you could use:

```
r = requests.get("http://www.ebay.com/itm/222378225962")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('div', 'itemAttr')

data = []
for label in table.select('th, td.attrLabels'):
    key = re.sub(r'\W+', '', label.text.strip())
    value = label.find_next_sibling().text.strip()

    data.append({ key: value })
```

Output:

```
> [{'Condition': 'Used'}, {'SellerNotes': '“Excellent Condition”'}, {'Year': '2015'}, {'VINVehicleIdentificationNumber': '2G1FJ1EW2F9192023'}, {'Mileage': '29,000'}, {'Transmission': 'Manual'}, {'Make': 'Chevrolet'}, {'BodyType': 'Coupe'}, {'Model': 'Camaro'}, {'Warranty': 'Vehicle has an existing warranty'}, {'Trim': 'SS Coupe 2-Door'}, {'VehicleTitle': 'Clear'}, {'Engine': '6.2L 6162CC 376Cu. In. V8 GAS OHV Naturally Aspirated'}, {'Options': 'Leather Seats'}, {'DriveType': 'RWD'}, {'SafetyFeatures': 'Anti-Lock Brakes, Driver Airbag, Passenger Airbag, Side Airbags'}, {'PowerOptions': 'Air Conditioning, Cruise Control, Power Locks, Power Windows, Power Seats'}, {'SubModel': '1LE'}, {'FuelType': 'Gasoline'}, {'ExteriorColor': 'White'}, {'ForSaleBy': 'Private Seller'}, {'InteriorColor': 'Black'}, {'DisabilityEquipped': 'No'}, {'NumberofCylinders': '8'}]
```