# python convert beautifulsoup output into dict/json

Tags: python, json, dictionary, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from a product page of amazon. I've got the entire markup with beautifulsoup. I want to get the necessary product details in the following json format

```
{
  asin: string,
  title: string,
  price: number,
  listPrice: number,
  prime: boolean,

  dimensions: {
    height: number,
    length: number,
    width: number,
    weight: number,
  },
  images: Array<string>,
  attributes: Array<{ name: string, value: string }>,
  categories: <{ node: string, title: string }>,

}
```

What I've understood I need to get the details in the dictionary format first. But not sure how to get these particular tags from the huge html to convert them into dict.

edit: my code looks like this

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00ILZH9BO"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
print(soup)
```

edit 2: I'm providing some of the html from which I need my product details

```
#######title#########
<span class="a-size-large" id="productTitle">
  MagicBrite Complete Teeth Whitening Kit At Home Whitening
</span>


  #########price#####
<span class="a-color-price">
    <span class="p13n-sc-price">$11.85</span>
</span>



  ############images#########

<li class="a-spacing-small item"><span class="a-list-item">
<span class="a-declarative" data-action="thumb-action" data-thumb-action='{"thumbnailIndex":4,"variant":"PT04","index":4,"type":"image"}'>
<span class="a-button a-button-thumbnail a-button-toggle"><span class="a-button-inner"><input class="a-button-input" type="submit"/><span aria-hidden="true" class="a-button-text">
<img alt="" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51f8kCdwmqL._SS40_.jpg"/>
</span></span></span>
</span>
</span></li>
<li class="a-spacing-small item"><span class="a-list-item">
<span class="a-declarative" data-action="thumb-action" data-thumb-action='{"thumbnailIndex":5,"variant":"PT05","index":5,"type":"image"}'>
<span class="a-button a-button-thumbnail a-button-toggle"><span class="a-button-inner"><input class="a-button-input" type="submit"/><span aria-hidden="true" class="a-button-text">
<img alt="" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/517mTOTBEiL._SS40_.jpg"/>
</span></span></span>
</span>
</span></li>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack! As a general rule when asking questions is to provide as much detail as possible. Including any code that you may have written and any other information such as the html for this particular problem. Also! you should try searching stack overflow for similar questions that have already been answered such as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42184367/parse-html-table-data-with-beautifulsoup-into-a-dict

Comment: Anusha thanks for the edit. But if you provide the html you wish to extract it will help encourage people to answer the question. By providing as much as possible it is more likely users will answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me! Actually the html is very large, I'm not sure how to upload that

Comment: You mention in your question that you want to extract product details. simply show the html structure where this information lies

Comment: added and edited! @JulianSilvestri

Answer (score 1):

Manually.

```
data = {
    'asin': soup.find(id="ASIN").attrs['value'],
    'title': soup.find(id="title").text.strip(),
    'price': soup.find(id="price").find(id="priceblock_ourprice").text.strip(),
    ....
}
```

The `price` seems to be a bit hidden, and it may be different on different pages where to find the actual "final price".

Finally, once you have your `dict` ready, just feed it to `json.dumps()`.

```
import json
result = json.dumps(data)
```

And if Amazon decides to change their mark-up, things may break.